# Woocommerce change quantity min limit for each product in cart

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, hook-woocommerce

I have couple of products that can only be bought if min quantity is over certain number.

I wrote and put a snippet of code in my child themes functions.php to change the min quantity for products.

```
function wpa116693_filter_min_quantity( $min, $product ){

    if ( has_term ( '5', 'product_tag' ) ){
        return 5;
    }

    if ( has_term ( '10', 'product_tag' ) ){
        return 10;
    }

    if ( has_term ( '6', 'product_tag' ) ){
        return 6;
    }
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_min', 'wpa116693_filter_min_quantity', 10, 2 );
```

So what it does is, if it finds a product with the tag 5 then it will change the quantity min to 5. this works in single product page but it doesn't work in cart page. I can go lower than the min quantity in the cart page. I believe it doesn't work because "has_term" does not work in the cart page.

I want it to work in cart page too.
Please help me solve this, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to hook your function to [`woocommerce_cart_loaded_from_session`](http://hookr.io/actions/woocommerce_cart_loaded_from_session/) like this:

```
add_action('woocommerce_cart_loaded_from_session', 'wh_checkAndUpdateCart');

function wh_checkAndUpdateCart()
{

    //if the cart is empty do nothing
    if (WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count() == 0)
    {
        return;
    }

    foreach (WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item)
    {
        $product_id = $cart_item['product_id']; // Product ID
        $product_qty = $cart_item['quantity']; // Product quantity

        if (has_term(5, 'product_tag', $product_id) && ($product_qty > 5))
        {
            WC()->cart->set_quantity($cart_item_key, 5);
        }
        if (has_term(10, 'product_tag', $product_id) && ($product_qty > 10))
        {
            WC()->cart->set_quantity($cart_item_key, 10);
        }
        if (has_term(6, 'product_tag', $product_id) && ($product_qty > 6))
        {
            WC()->cart->set_quantity($cart_item_key, 6);
        }
    }
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme). Or also in any plugin php files.*
**Code is tested and works.**

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hey, It works!!I Think you misunderstood me a little, just a little tho. I changed the if operator from ">" to "<" and I also had to wrap the numbers inside quotation marks after has_term. Wouldn't work otherwise, not sure why. 

2 more question, is it possible to put a min attribute to the quantity input through this?

and I have a ajax add to cart with quantity input on products page and when I click the add to cart button, it gets stuck on the spinning icon but it does add the product to the cart. It should give me a link below the button that says "view cart" and show check icon.

Comment: Sorry I did't get you on this : _it possible to put a min attribute to the quantity input through this_ -- Do you want to show cart error message for this? and for your 2nd question you need to post a new question with the code that you have written.

Comment: The quantity input has the attributes min and max. I want to hook min attribute code in your code so that people cant enter lower value than the minimum quantity in the input box. The code that I posted on my question works on single product page. I kinda fixed the 2nd question, tried changing "add_action" to "add_filter" and it started working without any problems. Maybe you had a different solution?

Comment: You have `product_id` so you have get the min max value and do the checking and if any checking fails throw error like this `wc_add_notice( __( 'You can not do that', 'textdomain' ), 'error' );`